# Change Form size - FormBorderStyle

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change window form size with FormBorderStyle == FixedSingle at runtime?

Using this code

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Size = new Size(this.Width, 0);
}
```

With property FormBorderStyle == Sizable, everysing is OK, and form looks like this 
[image]

But if property set to FixedSingle or FixedToolWindow some part of form is showed.
[image]

How to remove this part of form?

Comment: Wait, step back a bit. Why are you trying to resize the form like this? What's wrong with `Hide()`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hide() method is already realized. The second method is roll up the form in header.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. Do you want to collapse the form to just the title when it's deactivated?

Comment: Correct! Collaps the form when it's deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be something that's easily fixed - as soon as the form gets the window style associated with `FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle` (and friends), the client area expands. I've tried changing the client are calculations (`WM_NCCALCSIZE` and friends), but the only way I could make it smaller was by repainting the non-client area as well - depending on your exact case, that might or might not be a viable option.

However, you could change the border style to sizeable, while setting `MaxSize` and `MinSize` appropriately - this will prevent resizing while keeping the form's client area "invisible". For bonus points, you can handle `WM_NCHITTEST` to avoid the mouse-resizing entirely (just pretend the resize handles are actually the title / client area). When you activate the form again, just restore the old styles and settings.